# Any robot developed using BANANA Pi as platform?

Tags: ros, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know... the name does not inspire great confidence, but it is not my fault.

There really is a RPI-like (or BBB-like if you will) board that is called Banana Pi. In my opinion, its advantage, besides the Dual A7 processor, is the connection to a SATA device.

Can you imagine one of those with an SSD ?

Well, to the question: has anyone done ( or heard of) any ROS/robot development with one of those ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191448/any-robot-developed-using-banana-pi-as-platform-?/) by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2014-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am doing it !

---

Originally posted by [BJ1](https://answers.ros.org/users/21736/bj1/) with karma: 16 on 2015-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0